# How to set the Background image for UITableview for ios7 3.5 inches and 4-inches screen

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am working on ios application for iOS6 & iOS7 3.5 inches and 4-inches screen.I have some problem, when I set the background image for `UITableview`.In iOS 6 4-inches and 3.5 inches screen the tableview background image displayed.There is no problem for displaying.But my iOS7 3.5 & 4-inches the tableview background image not displaying.That is my problem.This is my code.

```
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0"))
{     
    weeklyTableview=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 60, 320, 480)];       
    weeklyTableview.dataSource=self;    
    weeklyTableview.delegate=self;      
    weeklyTableview.scrollEnabled=YES;

    [self.view addSubview:weeklyTableview];

    weeklyTableview.separatorStyle=UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
    weeklyTableview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;

    tableBackgroundImage=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dash-bord-bg-small.PNG"]];
    tableBackgroundImage.frame=weeklyTableview.frame;

    [weeklyTableview setBackgroundView:tableBackgroundImage];              
}
else
{

    weeklyTableview=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 60, 320, 480)];
    weeklyTableview.dataSource=self;        
    weeklyTableview.delegate=self;        
    weeklyTableview.scrollEnabled=YES;

    [self.view addSubview:weeklyTableview];

    weeklyTableview.separatorStyle=UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
    weeklyTableview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;

    tableBackgroundImage=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dash-bord-bg-small.PNG"]];
    tableBackgroundImage.frame=weeklyTableview.frame;

    [weeklyTableview setBackgroundView:tableBackgroundImage];

}
```

Comment: Did you try to set background color with those images?

Comment: I'm wondering whether when it runs on iOS 7 your `imageNamed:` is failing.

Comment: @Mani i am trying like this also.But it is not working for me.The background color display only view.But i want to display background image in UITableview.I am trying like this also:    [weeklyTableview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:2.0/255.0 green:28.0/255.0 blue:57.0/255.0 alpha:1]]];

Comment: By the way, your code is nutty. Both the `if` clause and the `else` clause are identical. What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I am trying to display background image for both versions.Displaying background image for ios6 is fine.But it is not working for ios7

Comment: @user3419311 : **fyi**... your if-else block is **identical**. ***Also***... you stated something about 3.5" and 4" but it seems the frame sizes is very 3.5" specific. *anyways*... **check if your bundle includes this `dash-bord-bg-small.PNG` file.**

Comment: help me any body plz.....

Comment: @user3419311 : **plus...** on the `UIImageView` object, you start with `-initWithImage:` and **later** change it's frame... ***doesn't matter*** (_you should do `-setContentMode:` and specify something like `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`_)

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly**, check if the file `dash-bord-bg-small.PNG` is present in the project bundle.

**Secondly**, please note that when playing with a `UIImageView` object, if you do `-initWithImage:` and specify an image of 64px by 64px, then the `imageView` frame set is equal to the dimension of the image.
Later, if you change the frame of this `imageView` object to, say, 320px by 320px, the image remains 64px by 64px while only the `imageView` object has become larger. (*Anyways... this isn't such a big issue for you at this moment*)

**Lastly**... note that the `UITableViewCell` in iOS6, by default, has a transparent background but in iOS7 it's background is white.

Try this and see if it helps:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [cell.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
}
```

---

***Optionally***... dump the **if-else** block since it's identical*

Comment: @user3419311 : what is the dimension of `dash-bord-bg-small.png`? do you see the `tabelView` cells? would you please take a screenshot and include it in your question?

Comment: @user3419311 : updated answer. it should be `cell.contentView` and not simply `cell`... hopefully...

Comment: bro the image should display background of view.for example if scroll the tableview the image displayed on view background.But i want to display tableview background...

Comment: @user3419311 : whats the frame of the `tableBackgroundImage` just after `-initWithImage:` (_but **before** `tableBackgroundImage.frame=weeklyTableview.frame;`_)?

Comment: tableBackgroundImage is the object name of the UIImageview bro

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    [weeklyTableview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dash-bord-bg-small.PNG"]]];
```